# World coordinates of ReactVR component

Tags: three.js, react-360

Is there a cross-platform way to get the absolute world coordinates of a ReactVR Component from within the component itself? I can't see any documented means of doing this, short of creating a custom native component.

The use-case is driving application logic based on the world-space proximity of components which may be in different `View` trees i.e. components may be transformed by different nested parent Views, but there should also be some way to know where they are relative to each other in 3D without resorting to platform-specific code.

Comment: As far as I can tell they've specifically chosen to not make such information available, [see this](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/180). Maybe you could open an issue and let them know of your use case.

Comment: perhaps each branch of your view tree could expose a function to give position, and then you could chain the functions?